# Not able to configure FFserver for RTSP

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, ffserver

I am kind of new to the streaming world... so, please forgive me if I ask kind of dumb question.

I am trying to stream my pre-recorded file over RTSP through FFserver.

My config file is :

```
RTSPPort 8544
<Feed feed2.ffm>
    File /home/xyz/tmp/feed2.ffm
    FileMaxSize 200K
    ACL allow 127.0.0.1
</Feed>

<Stream test.sdp>
    Feed feed2.ffm
    Format rtsp
    VideoFrameRate 15
    VideoSize 352x240
    VideoBitRate 256
    VideoBufferSize 40
    VideoGopSize 30
    AudioBitRate 64
    StartSendOnKey
</Stream>
```

After starting the server, it give the below log:

```
$ ./ffserver -f doc/ffserver.conf
ffserver version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
built on Sep 17 2012 19:46:38 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-aacenc 
-enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-version3
libavutil 51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
libavcodec 54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
libavformat 54. 6.100 / 54. 6.100
libavdevice 54. 0.100 / 54. 0.100
libavfilter 2. 77.100 / 2. 77.100
libswscale 2. 1.100 / 2. 1.100
libswresample 0. 15.100 / 0. 15.100
libpostproc 52. 0.100 / 52. 0.100
Wed Sep 19 17:03:32 2012 FFserver started.
```

And now from my VLC client I am trying to type the URL: rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8554/test.sdp

But, what happens is that, there is no response on the ffserver.

I have no clue what might be the problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You don't have anything to stream.
you need to start

```
ffmpeg -i <source> http://localhost:8090/feed2.ffm
```

IF you enable Port 8090 for http,
with the directive (in your config file)

```
Port 8090
```

This has been asked before, but badly tagged, so I can't find it.
If anybody finds it, please link it here. As starting an empty server seems to be common.

Answer (score 1):

Matthias is right. Currently you are not streaming anything.
And the given ffmpeg-command should work but you might want to consider, that maybe the feed section is contra productive.

If the video-file is already stored on the server, you don't need the feed (since the video itself will serve as one).

```
<Stream test.sdp>
File "path_to_your_file"   #instead of the Feed
...
</Stream>
```

If the video-file is on a different computer, you have to stream it to the server first (see Matthias' answer).

**Edit**:
Also you need the feed if you want to mess around with the stream before streaming.